# Extract the filename from a script variable

Tags: bash, macos

I've got a batch file like

`for f in bin/$1*.txt; do echo $f; done`

I'd like to echo just the filename - not bin/temp.txt or temp.txt - just temp.

How I can extract the filename from $f?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the suffix is always the same you can just use `basename -s ".txt" $f`.

Answer (score 0):

Parameter expansion.

```
$: f=bin/temp123.txt # an example you might have
$: x="${f#bin/}"     # asign to x without bin/ prefix
$: echo $x
temp123.txt
$: echo ${x%.txt}    # show x without .txt suffix
temp123
```